# R bigglm ffdf returns size-related error

Tags: r, bigdata, ff, ffbase

I am trying to run a logistic regression model on a `ffdf` using `bigglm.ffdf` from ffbase but I get an error:

```
x1 = as.ff(sample(0:5, 400, replace=T))
x2 = as.ff(sample(c(rep(0, 98), rep(1, 2)), 400, replace=T) )
df2 = ffdf(x1, x2)
mod = bigglm.ffdf(x2 ~ x1, family = binomial(), data = df2)

> Error in R[ok, ok] <- chol2inv(R[ok, ok, drop = FALSE]) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any insight as per what is wrong with the code? Many thanks in advance.

Edit: The ram objects run as expected:

```
x5 = sample( 0:5, 400, replace=T)
x6 = sample(c(rep(0, 98), rep(1, 2)), 400, replace=T)
df3 = data.frame(x5, x6)
mod = glm(x6 ~ x5, family = binomial(), data = df3)
# no error
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this using R 3.0.2 running biglm_0.9-1, ffbase_0.11.1, ff_2.2-11 with `set.seed(1212)` (but it does complain about non-convergence). Maybe try supplying `set.seed` to make your example with the error exactly reproducible and/or try updating the packages and see if the error disappears.

Comment: Bizarre. I run the code on a new session and it does work indeed (the non-conversion warning is no problem as the data is random). Still, it does not work for my existing session, where a lot of objects have been created etc. Why would that be?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue neither. Your code works fine in my setting (biglm_0.9-1, ffbase_0.9, ff_2.2-12). Maybe rm(x1, x2) might help?

Comment: Thanks guys. This question should be removed by a moderator. Something weird was going on with my session. Apologies.